# How to overlap between centers of edges while maintaining the uv shapes?

Tags: uv

[image]

I want to overlap the center of the bottom edge of the rectangle uv with the center of the top edge of the square uv.
How can I achieve this using Blender's uv editing tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get there with vertex snapping.

1. Use Face select mode, and center the first rectangle
2. Enable *Vertex snapping > Closest* and snap the second rectangle
3. Center the second rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I came up with a way to use the faces of scale 0.

Comment: Smart :). Blender should really get a better snapping functionality in UV editor.